# how to create passport token from android using retrofit send to api in laravel 5.7 and is there any better option than passport for authentication

Tags: android, laravel, retrofit, laravel-passport

Android retrofit should create passport token and send to laravel rest api and also add to database. Is there any better option than passport which can be used in laravel5.7 and android.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create token in android,you just need to send your info and in RegisterController

```
  $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    $client = Client::where('password_client', 1)->first();



    $request->request->add([
        'grant_type'    => 'password',
        'client_id'     => $client->id,
        'client_secret' => $client->secret,
        'username'      => $request->all()['email'],
        'password'      => $request->all()['password'],
        'scope'         => null,
    ]);

    // Fire off the internal request.
    $token = Request::create(
        'oauth/token',
        'POST'
    );
    return \Route::dispatch($token);
```

then it will return to you `access_token` and `expired_at`.

and in android you need to save token in sharedPreferences

```
public class TokenManager {

private SharedPreferences prefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

private static TokenManager INSTANCE = null;

private TokenManager(SharedPreferences prefs){
    this.prefs = prefs;
    this.editor = prefs.edit();
}

public static synchronized TokenManager getInstance(SharedPreferences prefs){
    if(INSTANCE == null){
        INSTANCE = new TokenManager(prefs);
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

public void saveToken(AccessToken token){
    editor.putString("ACCESS_TOKEN", token.getAccess_token()).commit();
    editor.putString("REFRESH_TOKEN", token.getRefresh_token()).commit();
}

public void deleteToken(){
    editor.remove("ACCESS_TOKEN").commit();
    editor.remove("REFRESH_TOKEN").commit();
}

public AccessToken getToken(){
    AccessToken token = new AccessToken();
    token.setAccess_token(prefs.getString("ACCESS_TOKEN", null));
    token.setRefresh_token(prefs.getString("REFRESH_TOKEN", null));
    return token;
}
```

in `RetrofitBuilder Class

```
public static <T> T createServiceWithAuth(Class<T> service, final TokenManager tokenManager) {

    OkHttpClient newClient = client.newBuilder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

            Request request = chain.request();

            Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder();

            if (tokenManager.getToken().getAccess_token() != null) {
                builder.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenManager.getToken().getAccess_token());
            }
            request = builder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    }).authenticator(CustomAuthenticator.getInstance(tokenManager)).build();

    Retrofit newRetrofit = retrofit.newBuilder().client(newClient).build();
    return newRetrofit.create(service);

}
```

in your activity

```
  TokenManager tokenManager;
  Routes service;
     service = RetrofitBuilder.createServiceWithAuth(Routes.class, tokenManager);
 tokenManager = TokenManager.getInstance(getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE));
```

then check if not null

```
if (tokenManager.getToken().getAccess_token() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MenuDrawerProfileActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```

to avoid start login page.
in retrofit response put this

```
  tokenManager.saveToken(response.body());
```

finally don't forget to declare AccessToken Model

```
  public class AccessToken {

    String token_type;
    int expires_in;
    String access_token;
    String refresh_token;
}
```

Hope it help you.